# Embed Contribution Page Error

Tags: contributions

D7.56 Civi4.7.22

I'm attempting to embed the bulk of a contribution page inside a block shown in a view. The view shows multiple of these blocks.

I copied them by using inspect to get the HTML underneath.

This works fine at first, however intermittently I experience the following error when clicking the button:

"Your browser session has expired and we are unable to complete your form submission. We have returned you to the initial step so you can complete and resubmit the form. If you experience continued difficulties, please contact us for assistance."

How can I circumvent this? I suppose that the HTML needs to be regenerated, not copy and pasted. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

John

My immediate thinking is that you will probably need to do some form of iframing on the block. The reason for that is that i don't think i can think of a way to have proper session keys and static html copied across. The session key is generated when the first step of the form is loaded. You may also need to look at a drupal module like themekey if you need to switch themes to make the iframe look nicer in the block

Seamus

Comment: Using themekey is a good suggestion. I'd tried iframes with snippet=1, but wasn't happy with the loading times.